# Host did not have any virtual network defined

Tags: templates, vmware, vsphere, powercli, vcenter

I am trying to automate importing template from my local machine to the Vcenter but facing error "host did not have virtual network defined".Can anyone look into this and please help me out.

```
param( 

[string]$Vcentername,  
[string]$Username,
[string]$Password,
[string]$Clustername
)
```

## connecting to vcenter

```
Connect-VIServer $Vcentername -user $Username -pass $Password
```

## importing OVF/OVA FILE configuration into a variable

```
$ovffile = "C:\Users\nsrira001c\Desktop\Linux_Rhel71_v1_gold_version_test\Linux_Rhel71_v1_gold_version_test.ovf"
$ovfconfig = Get-ovfconfiguration $ovffile
```

## 12 a List the properties of the OVF/OVA configuration

```
$ovfconfig
```

## parameters for the

```
$myCluster = Get-Cluster -Name $Clustername 

$VMHost = Get-Cluster $Clustername | Get-VMHost | sort MemoryGB | select -first 1 
$Datastore = $VMHost | Get-datastore | sort FreespaceGB -Descending | select -first 1
$Network = Get-VirtualPortGroup -Name "dv_HO_Backup_Green_305" -VMHost $VMHost
Import-vApp -Source $ovffile -VMHost $VMHost -Location $myCluster -Name "Linux_Rhel71_v1_gold_version_test"
```

---

WARNING: The output of the command produced distributed virtual portgroup objects. This behavior is obsolete and may
change in the future. To retrieve distributed portgroups, use Get-VDPortgroup cmdlet in the VDS component. To retrieve
standard portgroups, use -Standard.
Import-vApp : 10/17/2016 8:40:24 AM     Import-VApp             Host did not have any virtual network defined.
At C:\Users\nsrira001c\Desktop\Linux_template_deployment_code2.ps1:29 char:1
+ Import-vApp -Source $ovffile -VMHost $VMHost -Location $myCluster -Na ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-VApp], OvfNoHostNic
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_VappServiceImpl_ImportVApp_CreateImportSpecError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cm
   dlets.Commands.ImportVApp

Comment: I've faced the same problem but in context of Terraform deployment
And for me solution was in this [Vmware KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2076239) After 10 minutes of laughing under the table, i've embraced the fact that this article is 7 years old :D Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

You assume that your network adapter is on your first host.

$Network = Get-VirtualPortGroup -Name "dv_HO_Backup_Green_305" -VMHost $VMHost

$VMHost = The first in the list. Try entering the name that has that virtual port group attached to it.